# Bisecting intervals that have an upper bound of 4/n for a certain N<n

Tags: combinatorics

Let $x_1 \in (0, 1)$. Iteratively define intervals $I_1,I_2, \ldots$ and points $x_2,x_3, \ldots$ by: $I_k$ is the longest sub-interval of $(0, 1)$ not containing any of the points $x_i, \; 1 \le i \le k$ (if ties choose the leftmost interval) and $x_k$ is the midpoint of $I_{k−1}$. Prove
there is a number $N$ not depending on $x_1$, such that the length of $I_n$ does not exceed $\frac{20}{n}$ if $n \ge N$.

Comment: Please use MathJax for formatting your math.

Comment: Hi, why do you ask this question again? (The [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874590/bisections-of-the-unit-line-inequality)).

Comment: Its very tough for me to comprehend

Comment: Alex ravsky , what college do u teach at ? I would love to stop in and u tutor me on this problem that has bugged me for many a moons ( and suns ( day) lol) I want to find a way to animate the bisections for a given initial point ( x1) on the line and see what values emmerge all less then 4/n for as u said n>3